# very very hard Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, union

I have a table as follows:

```
**A----B----C----D----F----E**

1----2----3-----4----5----6

1----2----3-----4----5----6

1----2----3-----4----5----6
```

---

Now I want to make a query that table to table below lead the field values c, d of the following columns A, B, the values in column F, E the following columns A, B,

---

The final table

```
**A----B**

1----2

1----2

1----2

3----4

3----4

3----4

5----6

5----6

5----6
```

Comment: A very, very hard question with a very, very easy answer. ;-)

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Those are two very different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a AS A, b AS B 
FROM tablea 
UNION ALL
SELECT c AS A, d AS B 
FROM tablea 
UNION ALL
SELECT f AS A, e AS B 
FROM tablea;
```

Comment: very very Thanks saharsh shah. your code good and OK. but i want create group of A columns . after create your code less the create group icon in query builder vb.net.

Answer (score 2):

You want a basic `union all` query:

```
select a, b from table t union all
select c, d from table t union all
select f, e from table t;
```